# Higher order iterators in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iterator

I was reading a Ruby question about the `.each` iterator, and someone stated that using `.each` can be a code smell if higher order iterators are better suited for the task. What are higher order iterators in Ruby?

**edit:** Jörg W Mittag, the author of the StackOverflow answer that I was referring to mentioned that he meant to write higher *level* iterators, but he also explained what they are very well below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oops. I meant higher-*level* iterators, not higher-*order*. *Every* iterator is of course by definition higher-order.

Basically, iteration is a very low-level concept. The purpose of programming is to communicate intent to the other stakeholders on the team. "Initializing an empty array, then iterating over another array and adding the current element of this array to the first array if it is divisible by two without a remainder" is *not* communicating intent. "Selecting all even numbers" *is*.

In general, you almost never iterate over a collection just for iteration's sake. You either want to

- transform each element in some way (that's usually called `map`, in Ruby and Smalltalk it's `collect` and in .NET and SQL it's `Select`),
- reduce the whole collection down to some single value, e.g. computing the sum or the average or the standard deviation of a list of football scores (in category theory, that's called a *catamorphism*, in functional programming it is `fold` or `reduce`, in Smalltalk it's `inject:into:`, in Ruby it's `inject` and in .NET `Aggregate`),
- filter out all elements that satisfy a certain condition (`filter` in most functional languages, `select` in Smalltalk and Ruby, also `find_all` in Ruby, `Where` in .NET and SQL),
- filter out all elements that *do not* satisfy a condition (`reject` in Smalltalk and Ruby)
- find the first element that satisfies a condition (`find` in Ruby)
- count the elements thats satisfy a condition (`count` in Ruby)
- check if all elements (`all?`), at least one element (`any?`) or no elements (`none?`) satisfy a condition
- group the elements into buckets based on some discriminator (`group_by` in Ruby, .NET and SQL)
- partition the collection into two collections based on some predicate (`partition`)
- sort the collection (`sort`, `sort_by`)
- combine multiple collections into one (`zip`)
- and so on and so forth …

Almost *never* is your goal to just iterate over a collection.

In particular, `reduce` aka. `inject` aka. `fold` aka. `inject:into:` aka. `Aggregate` aka. *catamorphism* is your friend. There's a reason why it has such a fancy-sounding mathematical name: it is extremely powerful. In fact, most of what I mentioned above, can be implemented in terms of `reduce`.

Basically, what `reduce` does, is it "reduces" the entire collection down to a single value, using some function. You have some sort of accumulator value, and then you take the accumulator value and the first element and feed it into the function. The result of that function then becomes the new accumulator, which you pair up with the second element and feed to the function and so on.

The most obvious example of this is summing a list of numbers:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].reduce(0) {|acc, elem|
  acc + elem
}
```

So, the accumulator starts out as `0`, and we pass the first element `4` into the `+` function. The result is `4`, which becomes the new accumulator. Now we pass the next element `8` in and the result is `12`. And this continues till the last element and the result is that they were dead the whole time. No, wait, the result is `108`.

Ruby actually allows us to take a couple of shortcuts: If the element type is the same as the accumulator type, you can leave out the accumulator and Ruby will simply pass the first element as the first value for the accumulator:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].reduce {|acc, elem|
  acc + elem
}
```

Also, we can use `Symbol#to_proc` here:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].reduce(&:+)
```

And actually, if you pass `reduce` a `Symbol` argument it will treat as the name of the function to use for the reduction operation:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].reduce(:+)
```

However, summing is not all that `reduce` can do. In fact, I find this example a little dangerous. Everybody I showed this to, immediately understood, "Aah, so *that's* what a `reduce` is", but unortunately some also thought that summing numbers is *all* `reduce` is, and that's definitely not the case. In fact, `reduce` is a *general method of iteration*, by which I mean that `reduce` can do *anything* that `each` can do. In particular, you can store arbitrary state in the accumulator.

For example, I wrote above that `reduce` reduces the collection down to a single value. But of course that "single value" can be arbitrarily complex. It could, for example, be itself a collection. Or a string:

```
class Array
  def mystery_method(foo)
    drop(1).reduce("#{first}") {|s, el| s << foo.to_str << el.to_s }
  end
end
```

This is an example how far you can go with playing tricks with the accumulator. If you try it out, you'll of course recognize it as `Array#join`:

```
class Array
  def join(sep=$,)
    drop(1).reduce("#{first}") {|s, el| s << sep.to_str << el.to_s }
  end
end
```

Note that nowhere in this "loop" do I have to keep track of whether I'm at the last or second-to-last element. Nor is there any conditional in the code. There is no potential for fencepost errors here. If you think about how to implement this with `each`, you *would* have to somehow keep track of the index and check whether you are at the last element and then have an `if` in there, to prevent emitting the separator at the end.

Since I wrote above that all iteration can be done with `reduce`, I might just as well prove it. Here's Ruby's `Enumerable` methods, implemented in terms of `reduce` instead of `each` as they normally are. (Note that I only just started and have only arrived at *g* yet.)

```
module Enumerable
  def all?
    reduce(true) {|res, el| res && yield(el) }
  end

  def any?
    reduce(false) {|res, el| res || yield(el) }
  end

  alias_method :map, def collect
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res << yield(el) }
  end

  def count
    reduce(0) {|res, el| res + 1 if yield el }
  end

  alias_method :find, def detect
    reduce(nil) {|res, el| if yield el then el end unless res }
  end

  def drop(n=1)
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el unless n -= 1 >= 0 }}
  end

  def drop_while
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el unless yield el }}
  end

  def each
    reduce(nil) {|_, el| yield el }
  end

  def each_with_index
    tap { reduce(-1) {|i, el| (i+1).tap {|i| yield el, i }}}
  end

  alias_method :select, def find_all
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el if yield el }}
  end

  def grep(pattern)
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << yield(el) if pattern === el }}
  end

  def group_by
    reduce(Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }) {|res, el| res.tap {|res|
        res[yield el] = el
    }}
  end

  def include?(obj)
    reduce(false) {|res, el| break true if res || el == obj }
  end

  def reject
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el unless yield el }}
  end
end
```

[Note: I made some simplifications for the purpose of this post. For example, according to the standard Ruby Enumerable protocol, `each` is supposed to return `self`, so you'd have to slap an extra line in there; other methods behave slightly differently, depending on what kind and how many arguments you pass in and so on. I left those out because they distract from the point I am trying to make.]

Answer (score 5):

They're talking about more specialized methods such as `map`, `filter` or `inject`. For example, instead of this:

```
even_numbers = []
numbers.each {|num| even_numbers << num if num.even?}
```

You should do this:

```
even_numbers = numbers.select {|num| num.even?}
```

It says *what* you want to do but encapsulates all the irrelevant technical details in the `select` method. (And incidentally, in Ruby 1.8.7 or later, you can just write `even_numbers = numbers.select(&:even?)`, so even more concise if slightly Perl-like.)

These aren't normally called "higher-order iterators," but whoever wrote that probably just had a minor mental mixup. It's a good principle whatever terminology you use.

Comment: *whoever wrote that probably just had a minor mental mixup* -- Yes, I did :-)

Comment: BTW: This is the post in question: http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/3493583/iterating-hash-collection/3493724/#3493724 . I obviously fixed the error since then.

Answer (score 3):

From the usual definition of "higer-order" I would say a higher-order iterator is an iterator which takes an iterator as an argument or returns an iterator. So something like `enum_for` maybe. However I don't think this is what the person meant.

I think the person meant iterators like `map` or `select` which are higher-order functions, but did not realize that `each` is of course also a higher-order function. So basically this is just a case of terminological confusion.

The point of the poster presumably was that you should not use `each` in cases where `map`, `select` or `inject` could naturally be used instead. And to make that point he used a term, that didn't really make sense in that context.

Comment: It's much simpler than that: I meant to write higher-*level*.

Comment: @Jörg: Well, if I had known that you were the person in question, I wouldn't have assumed that you misunderstood what higher-order meant ;-)

Comment: BTW: This is the post in question: http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/3493583/iterating-hash-collection/3493724/#3493724 . I obviously fixed the error since then.

Answer (score 0):

I get this question a fair bit, so I blogged about the most commonly used iterators: select and reject. In the post there are examples of where 'each' is used incorrectly and how to correct the code to use either 'select' or 'reject'. Anyway, I hope it helps.

http://www.natontesting.com/2011/01/01/rubys-each-select-and-reject-methods/

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote a blog that is very relavent to this question - The reason you want to use higher order functions is that doing so elevates the programmer to a higher level of abstraction, to a point that a problem can be expressed declaratively, pushing the implementation down either to the Ruby standard library or lower level code.

http://www.railstutors.com/blog/declarative-thinking-with-higher-order-functions-and-blocks#.UG5x6fl26jJ